# SendNotifyMessage do not send correct messages

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

From one thread I send the message to main thread in window procedure.
But it is unsuccessful. When I send messages from the same thread - all is ok

```
include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>


#define MAX_THREADS 1

HWND m_wnd;

enum
{
    EVENT_CALL = (WM_APP + 0x30),
};


static LRESULT CALLBACK function_call()
{
    //some code
    int test = 0;
    return 0;
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK http_message_proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case EVENT_CALL:
            function_call();
            return 0;
        }
    return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void CreateNotifyWnd()
{
    WNDCLASSEX   w = { 0 };
    w.cbSize = sizeof(w);
    w.hInstance = (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase;
    w.lpszClassName = L"uistone_http_event_wnd";
    w.lpfnWndProc = http_message_proc;
    ::RegisterClassEx(&w);
    int error = GetLastError();
    m_wnd = ::CreateWindowEx(0, w.lpszClassName, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, w.hInstance, 0);
    error = GetLastError();
}


DWORD WINAPI SendThread(void* request_param)
{
    ::SendNotifyMessage(m_wnd, EVENT_CALL, 11, 12);
    int error = GetLastError();
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    CreateNotifyWnd();
    HANDLE  hThreadArray[MAX_THREADS];

    hThreadArray[0] = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, SendThread, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    //::SendNotifyMessage(m_wnd, EVENT_CALL, 11, 12);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    return 0;
}
```

Why I can not catch messages from another thread?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to have a message loop...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: 1) Where is your message loop? 2) How to you verify that your code catches or doesn't catch the message?

Comment: http_message_proc is function of loop in program

Comment: And I want have a signal after my thread will be finished.

Comment: I check it by breakpoints in MSVS2015 `http_message_proc` - message loop

Answer (score 1):

This is documented behavior. This is the relevant part from the [SendNotifyMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644953.aspx) documentation:

> If the window was created by the calling thread, SendNotifyMessage calls the window procedure for the window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message. **If the window was created by a different thread, SendNotifyMessage passes the message to the window procedure and returns immediately; it does not wait for the window procedure to finish processing the message.**

This appears to work when used with a window created on the same thread, because when you call `SendNotifyMessage`, the function synchronously calls into the window procedure associated with the target window before returning.

If the call crosses threads, on the other hand, you'd have to run a message loop for the - now queued - message to get picked up and passed to the window procedure<sup>1)</sup>. Your application doesn't run a message loop, and it exits before the message ever reaches the target window.

To fix this you'd have to run a message loop. This may or may not be the right approach to your problem. Since we don't know, what problem you are trying to solve, we cannot suggest potentially superior approaches and solutions.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *See [About Messages and Message Queues: Message Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx#routing).*

Comment: I created message loop for window in `CreateNotifyWnd`

Comment: @MartinJuin: Not in the code you posted. You registered a [window procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632593.aspx), but there is no loop that drains the message queue or dispatches messages.

Comment: Ok, I see - it is my error - no loop. But were I must write this loop and how?

Comment: @MartinJuin: If you want to ask a different question, click the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) link at the top of this page.

Comment: @MartinJuin in your example, you need a message loop in `main()` after creating the window and starting the thread. You can use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` to wait on the thread and the message queue at the same time, it will tell you which one satisfies the wait. If it is a message, retrieve it and dispatch it so the window can process it.